# How to visualize the ratio of two elasticsearch events in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I am using elasticsearch-1.4.4 and Kibana-4.0.1. I have two events logged into elasticsearch, and I want to visualize the ratio of these two events in Kibana.

The data types of the two events are integers.

Is there a way to do this in Kibana?

Comment: No, sorry. Kibana isn't capable of correlating two or more log entries.

Comment: What about latest versions of Kibana i.e Kibana-4.0.1  Are they capable?

Comment: No. You'll have to run some kind of stream processor that does this correlation.

Comment: Logstash is the wrong place for this.  You should query elasticsearch itself for the information.